# Plesk - 502 bad gateway frequently

Tags: nginx, plesk, parallels

I'm facing with this error from few days, maybe weeks. I've tried and tried and tried all kind of solutions over the internet but with no success, so:

I have a dedicated server with Plesk 12 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

This error appear daily, 1-2 times per day and I have to restart whole server and then all websites are working properly until next time this error appear again.

First time it appeared when I have added two more domains to be hosted. I suspected high server loading but no, rams never gets almost completely and cpu load is max 20%.

PS: Error appear only on websites, so I can access Plesk Panel and reboot server.

NGINX error log (/var/log/nginx/error.log):

```
[error] 1406#0: *119083 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: IP, server: , request: "GET http://www.example.com/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://SERVER_IP:7080/", host: "www.example.com"
```

It is first time when I'm using Plesk and I don't really know how to do or check... .

PS: Can this be caused by a cron job service?
Cron log which is worrying me:

```
254 postfix/master[1664]: warning: master_wakeup_timer_event: service pickup(public/pickup): Connection refused
```

Comment: Your DNS settings are corrupt, either e-mail your support for the provider to fix it, or if you have access to those settings, try fix them yourself.

Comment: Any hint to point me on?

Comment: I am having the exact smilar problem. Have you find any solution about this? Odin's website have not got enough information about this problem.

Comment: The problem simply disappeared. I suspect that there was a large amount of traffic and the server were not able to handle it and push 502 error.

Answer (score 0):

```
"(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream"
```

this error means that something goes wrong with Apache or PHP-FPM(if you have using it), check apache logs of site where it happens: /var/www/vhosts/examples.com/logs/error_log